# How to extract the Boost interprocess library

Tags: boost

I have a small project that is using only the `boost::interprocess` part from the Boost library.

Is there an easy way of extracting all needed files only for that part of the library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Boost [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) utility. To extract `interprocess` only, you could use:

```sh
$ mkdir /tmp/interprocess #bcp needs this
$ bcp interprocess /tmp/interprocess
```

This copies *interprocess* and dependencies to `/tmp/interprocess`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was blind, because I didn't found anything about that tool